# EWS - Image size/measurements

Tags: c#, asp.net, exchangewebservices

**I need to check if the image has special messurements like 25px25p so i do not save all images from our mailsigniture** (Xing, LinkedIn, Twitter, etc.). Retrieveing the images from the mail works how it should.

I have a little program which retrieves emails from the server and saves them to database. It also saves all Attachments. The necessary code part looks like this:

```
else if (attachment is FileAttachment || attachment.IsInline)
{
    FileAttachment fileAttachment = attachment as FileAttachment;
    fileAttachment.Load();

    string sfilename = fileAttachment.Name;
    string sContentType = fileAttachment.ContentType;

    using (var fs = new MemoryStream(fileAttachment.Content))
    {
         using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs))
         {
              byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);

              var oSQLConnection = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["..."].ConnectionString);
              var cmd = new SqlCommand();
              cmd.Connection = oSQLConnection;
              cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
              string sTicketID = gTicketID.ToString() ?? string.Empty;
              cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TBL_Attachment (fkTicketID, fkMailID, FileName, ContentType, Data)VALUES('"+sTicketID+"', '"+snFile+"', '"+sfilename+"', '"+sContentType+"', @Data)";

              var DataParameter = new SqlParameter("@Data", SqlDbType.Binary);
              cmd.Parameters.Add(DataParameter);
              DataParameter.Value = bytes; 

.
.
.
```

I convert the file to byte and save it to the database.

**Is it possible to get the file/image messurements for an if statement?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an obvious solution. I just had to convert my MemoryStream to Image and check with and hight.

```
using (var fs = new MemoryStream(fileAttachment.Content))
{
    Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(fs);
    if (!(image.Width == 190 && image.Height == 45) )
    {
        using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs))
        {
         ...
```